# readyState will not change to 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, readystate

I am trying to create a dynamic AJAX search bar which communicates with my database. Here is my code.

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject(){
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else{
    alert("Your browser does not support our dynamic search");
}
}

var search = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

function ajaxSearch(){
    if (search.readyState == 4 || search.readyState == 0){
        var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
        search.open("GET", 'searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
        search.onreadystatechange.handleSearchSuggest;
        search.send(null);
    }
}

function handleSearchSuggest(){
    if(search.readyState == 4){
        var ss = document.getElementById('ajaxSearch');
        ss.innerHTML = '';
        var str = search.responseText.split("\n");
        for(i=0; i<str.length-1; i++){
            var suggestion = '<div onmouseover="javascript:suggestOver(this);"';
            suggestion += 'onmouseout="javascript.suggestOut(this);"';
            suggestion += 'onclick="javascript:setSearch(this.innerHTML);"';
            suggestion += 'class="suggestLink">' + str[i] + '<div>';
            ss.innerHTML += suggestion;
        }
    }
}

function suggestOver(divValue){
    divValue.className = "suggestLink";
}

function suggestOut(divValue){
    divValue.className = "suggestLink";
}

function setSearch(x){
    document.getElementById('searchBox').value = x;
    document.getElementById('ajaxSearch').innerHTML = '';
}
```

The problem is that the readyState is changing from 0 to 1, but then it will not change to any other state. I need it to change to 4 to enter the function **handleSearchSuggest()**.
I also get this error within the console:
**TypeError: search.onreadystatechange is null**

Comment: what is this line ? : "search.onreadystatechange.handleSearchSuggest;"

Comment: It is a callback function

Comment: It's a call to an undefined attribute, not pointing to your callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the callback function correctly.

```
search.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
```

Note that a ready state of 1 means `OPENED` and 4 means `DONE`. You can test this via properties of the `XMLHttpRequest` class:

```
XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT == 0
XMLHttpRequest.OPENED == 1
XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED == 2
XMLHttpRequest.LOADING == 3
XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
search.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
```